# How to filter a Listview when typed the word in an edittext + simplecursoradapter

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, simplecursoradapter

I am developing a dictionary.Iam facing problem while filtering data from the list view. I have used Simple Cursor Adapter for list view. filtering the list view is not working. I have gone through some of the questions already asked here, still couldn't resolve the problem. Please have a look at the code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the adapter cursor to the one aquired with the filter.

Comment: i meant change the cursor on the adapter. like adapter.changeCursor(cursor);i think this will automatically call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter but if it doesnt try to include: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after changeCursor(cursor);